# Is there a website for introducing inner function List and reference of Julia?

Tags: julia

I found a website("http://www.jlhub.com/julia/manual/en/"), but the contents seem out-of-date.Is there a website to support the latest version?

Comment: This is a great concise reference to get started with Julia: https://syl1.gitbook.io/julia-language-a-concise-tutorial/language-core/data-types , though it does not have the entire function list. Navigate through the menu on the left of this page to go through the section that interests you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Julia website is https://julialang.org, and you can find all of the official resources for Julia linked from there, including the docs:

- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/

I'm not sure what "inner function List" means—do you want to know what functions come built in with Julia? If so, then that list starts here:

- https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/